# Converting json string to object inside random number of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm having a problem how to change json string inside json object for random number of objects. Let me explain this further with my code and comments.

I have factory which provides json objects

```
//Factory for products
app.factory('productsFactory', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location){
    var factory = {};
    factory.getlatestProductsList = function(n){
        return $http.get($location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/products/latest/'+n);
    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

This factory returns some random number of objects

```
0: Object
active: "1"
alias: "baumbach-circle"
date_c: "2016-01-06 08:09:54"
date_u: null
description: "Corrupti fugit iste quo sunt quidem voluptatibus dolorem. Eos velit architecto veritatis doloribus. Corporis sequi cupiditate possimus voluptates ut consequatur. Accusantium libero qui est sunt et."
id_category: "46"
id_product: "25"
id_user: "177"
images: "[{"thumbImage":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/250\/150\/?63763","image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/1024\/768\/?52630","position":0},{"thumbImage":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/250\/150\/?99795","image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/1024\/768\/?84669","position":1},{"thumbImage":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/250\/150\/?17506","image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/1024\/768\/?88926","position":2},{"thumbImage":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/250\/150\/?73869","image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/1024\/768\/?91917","position":3},{"thumbImage":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/250\/150\/?70019","image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/1024\/768\/?18509","position":4}]"
name: "Baumbach Circle"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
active: "1"
alias: "elta-road"
date_c: "2016-01-06 08:09:53"
date_u: null
description: "Culpa perferendis dolores rerum deleniti vero cumque. Similique explicabo beatae est quo sit nisi. Et a voluptatem nihil in. Voluptates modi qui est ducimus corrupti."
id_category: "46"
id_product: "24"
id_user: "73"
images: "[{"thumbImage":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/250\/150\/?53746","image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/1024\/768\/?49502","position":0},{"thumbImage":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/250\/150\/?75052","image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/1024\/768\/?77727","position":1},{"thumbImage":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/250\/150\/?32463","image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/1024\/768\/?76121","position":2},{"thumbImage":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/250\/150\/?61377","image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/1024\/768\/?89434","position":3},{"thumbImage":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/250\/150\/?86873","image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/1024\/768\/?82513","position":4}]"
name: "Elta Road"
__proto__: Object
```

The problem is that images json is in string format, so i have to use JSON.parse (at least i think so, since i'm new to this) to convert them to JSON

My question is: Is there some simple nice way to parse all images data to json or do i have to do this with forEach and if so, how would the code look like. I wan't to achieve this effect inside factory, so i don't have to repeat the code in every controller which is calling this factory.

If you need any additional info please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*how would the code look like*" - what are you stuck on? It sounds like you know how to use JSON.parse, and how to use forEach; you mostly sound like you're all set, since it shouldn't need to be complex. I'm not accusing you of being lazy for posting that as a question, I'm just genuinely unsure what you need help with.
EDIT: Scratch that, forgot the async/then part, which can certainly trip up someone's thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit the answer returned by the $http before returning it

```
app.factory('productsFactory', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location){
    var factory = {};
    factory.getlatestProductsList = function(n){
        var url = $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/products/latest/'+n;
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // you can edit the response her, and parse it
            return response ;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

Comment: Yes this is the way i was thinking off how to do it, but i hoped for some smoother solution instead of writing whole forEach shenanigans. So basically i'm searching for those edit response lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that $http returns a promise and then do some processing on the data before returning the promise. Does this work for you - let me know whether you need in ES5

```
factory.getlatestProductsList = function(n){
    return $http.get($location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/products/latest/'+n)
    .then(data => data.map(elem => {
       var tmp = Json.parse(elem.images);
       elem.images = tmp
       return elem;
    }));
```

in es5

```
factory.getlatestProductsList = function(n){
    return $http.get($location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/products/latest/'+n)
    .then(function(data) {
       return data.map(function(elem) {
         var tmp = Json.parse(elem.images);
         elem.images = tmp
         return elem;
       });
    });
```

Comment: Looks good, but I think he asked to do it inside the factory rather than on each call. Given that this is also just modifying, not transforming, you might be able to do it with forEach rather than map.

Comment: i never see the use of `=>` in javascript. how this is called  please?

Comment: that's a ES2015 'fat arrow' and is shorthand for an anonymous function call

Comment: @SimonH Given we're still not quite in the ES2015 days, you may want to stick to standard JS, under the assumption people don't understand to replace it.

Comment: let me try and i will let you know

Comment: ok i tried es5 option and i get the following two errors... productsFactory.getlatestProductsList(...).success is not a function and data.map is not a function

Comment: still same errors even doe i have added additional } which is missing at the end, for closing first function(n). How come .success is not a function?

Answer (score 0):

Pasting code if somebody wants to see how it looks like

```
//Factory for products
app.factory('productsFactory', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location){
    var factory = {};
    factory.getlatestProductsList = function(n){
        var url = $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/products/latest/'+n;
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            var pros = response.data;
            pros.forEach(function(item){
                var pictures = JSON.parse(item.images);
                delete item.images;
                item.images = pictures;
            })
            return pros;
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('error fetching latest products: ' + response);
        });
    }
    return factory;
}]);
```